# map which will return the same value by any String key

Tags: scala, collections

I have method interface with input parameter map. I want to add calling this method when this map will return the same value by any String key.
Could you help me to define the map which will return the same value by any String key?

```
def test(m: Map[String, Int]): Unit = {
  // some logic
}

val m = Map((???, 1))

m("")
res0: Int = 1

m("a")
res0: Int = 1

m("b")
res0: Int = 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try defining an empty `Map` with a default value for all the missing keys.

```scala
// updated after @Scalway's suggestion
val m = Map.empty[String, Int].withDefaultValue(1)

@ m("") 
//res1: Int = 1

@ m("a") 
//res2: Int = 1

@ m("asjkdhfk") 
//res3: Int = 1
```

or if you want to do some computation:

```scala
val m = Map.empty[String, Int].withDefault(k => ???)
```

Comment: or if you don't care about input string at all you can use also `Map.empty[String, Int].withDefaultValue(1) `